# WinForms and SQL Server, adding stored procedures to the database.mdf?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, winforms, stored-procedures

I have a winforms project along with a SQL Server project in Visual Studio 2013. I would like to create stored procedures to use on the SQL project.

When I go to the database and right click on stored procedure -> add procedure, and after writing the procedure, I'm prompted to save the SQL file.  So I picked the main directory of the project, but when I go to run the project, it is not recognizing the stored procedure.

My conclusion was that the SQL file is not getting inserted into the database, since even after I run the program, the stored procedures folder under the database has nothing.

I'm not sure how to actually insert the stored procedures into the "database.mdf" project.  This project is shared on GitHub also, so I would like for the other people to be able to access the stored procedures.

Comment: Creating a store procedure, is just some .SQL file with a command in it. You can save the .SQL file in your project, but that doesn't mean indeed that the stored procedure is on the database. You still need to execute the query , or if your file is in your database project to deploy the solution.

Comment: I understand, so what i'm trying to figure out is how to actually execute it so that it gets loaded into the database...I try to save the file in the project and then call the stored procedure but it is not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When your file is open, go in the SQL menu, and click execute :=)

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but is there a way to create or replace stored procedures, that way if i'm making changes to the file then I won't get the error that the object is already in the database?

Comment: Replace CREATE PROCEDURE by ALTER PROCEDURE =)

Answer (score 0):

The CREATE PROCEDURE script that is part of the SSDT project is just source code.  You need to build and publish the database project in order for the stored procedure to become part of the target database.

The primary output of the database build is a DACPAC file that has all of the objects needed to create a new database or upgrade an existing one.  When the DACPAC is published, SSDT creates, alters, or drops objects as needed so that the target database schema matches the source database project.  The SQL Server database engine manages the "mdf" file, not SSDT.  That allows you have multiple installations of the same database schema but with different data.

Comment: How do i go about building and publishing the database/DACPAC?  Is that what a dll is for?

Comment: You can build and publish an SSTD project directly from the VS 2013 IDE build menu.